# Jenkins render email-ext template to use for other purpose

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, email-ext

I have an html email template the represents my pipeline result.
I'm sending the render template by:

```
    emailext body: '${SCRIPT, template="feedback.template"}',
        subject: "Full pipeline details",
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        to: "${config.to}"
```

I try to send the rendered html report also via slack by:

```
    slackUploadFile filePath: "<MY-rendered-html>", initialComment:  "Full Report"
```

I can't figure out how to get the rendered email-template html for other purpose like sending the html via slack or uploading it to somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `saveOutput: true` [option](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/)